# Selecting a subarray in a javascript object using jQuery/jHashtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have an object like this:

```
var data = {
"info" : [{
"title": "Desemberkonsert",
"description": "MangerFHS 09/10"
}],
"playlist" : [
{
"title": "In This Place",
"description": "Excalibur",
"href": "desemberkonsert_in-this-place",
"url": "flv/desemberkonsert/21_in_this_place.flv",
"thumbnail": "flv/desemberkonsert/21_in_this_place_thumbnail.png",
"time": "5:39"
}]
}
```

And I am trying to do a search using jHashtables containsValue-function (I am willing to settle for any other search method that works though), like this `containsValue(data.playlist, 'Excalibur')`. But for some reason, this returns *false*. How would I select the array that contains the the value **Excalibur** from the code above?

Comment: Use the TAB key to improve the formatting of your code. (or http://jsbeautifier.com)

Comment: `data.playlist[0].description`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a decent method inherently available in JavaScript or the jQuery library, but using a smaller library named jLinq (http://jlinq.hugoware.com/), doing it was a breeze. It allows me to filter with many different methods (I am using the 3.x beta though).

EDIT: The thing I missed was that the lowest arrays behave like objects too. But as [Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/sime-vidas) pointed out, I can select a subarray like this: `data.playlist[0]`, and an item within that like this: `data.playlist[0].description`.